# Reveal a div with dynamic height underneath another div inside a container?

Tags: javascript, html, css, sass, margin

So, I have a box of content that has a title and a description, which are positioned at the bottom of the div. Initially, the description is hidden. What I'm trying to do is when you hover over the div, the title should move up and reveal the description, which has a dynamic height.

Here's what I have now: https://codepen.io/tayanderson/pen/qJrmXE

The problem is that it wouldn't display correctly if the description was 1 line or 3 lines. The title div should move up depending on the size of the description div.

[Here's an example of what I'm trying to do](https://spendtenseventeen.com/?utm_source=tokyosmoke.com&utm_medium=referral&utm_content=spendtenseventeenlockup&utm_term=&utm_campaign=TSTenSeventeen18)

HTML

```
<div class="grid-item" style="background-image: url(https://source.unsplash.com/WLUHO9A_xik/1600x900);">
  <div class="title">Title</div>
  <div class="desc">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.grid-item {
  height:300px;
  background-size: cover;
  width:300px;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  color: #fff;

  .title {
     position: absolute;
     left: 0;
     bottom: 0;
     width: 100%;
     padding: 0 20px;
  }

  .desc {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    transform: translateY(100%);
    padding: 5px 20px;
 }

  &:hover .title {
    bottom: 30%;
 }
  &:hover .desc {
    transform: translateY(0%);
 }
}
```

Comment: It seems like 3 people answered this question and all 3 answered in a way that you deem to be unhelpful for your situation.  In those types of situations, it probably means the specifications need to be made clearer.  Next time, please clarify what you are trying to do and comment on answers so that they can be improved instead of downvoting everyone's answers without commenting.

Comment: You're right, my question wasn't clear. I tried to edit to make it clearer. I didn't downvote anybody...

Comment: My apologies, please ignore my previous comment as it was directed at whomever did the downvoting

Answer (score 0):

It this what you meant?

```css
.inner, .inner:hover .grid-item.inner {
  -webkit-transition:all linear 0.2s;
  transition:all linear 0.2s;
}

.inner {
  background: #afa;
  width: 300px;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: absolute;
}

.grid-item:hover .inner{
  margin-top: -100px;
}
```

```html
<a class="grid-item" href="{{ .Permalink }}" style="background-image: url(images/recipes/{{.Params.image}})">
    <div class="inner"><h3 class="title is-3">{{.Title}}</h3></div>
    <div class="content"><p class="grid-item-blurb">{{.Description}}</p></div>     
</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that I reversed the order of the inner elements.

```css
.body {
  background: #aaf;
  height: 100px;
  width: 300px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.inner, .content {
  transition: all linear 0.2s;
}

.content {
  height: 100%;
}

.inner {
  background: #afa;
  transform: translateY(100%);
  top: 100%;
}

.body:hover .inner,
.body:hover .content {
  transform: translateY(-100%);
}
```

```html
<div class="body">
  <div class="content">
    Blue is a viewport (&lt;body&gt;, visible part of a page), which content should be compressed upon green slide-in
  </div>
  <div class="inner">Green is variable-height text which slides in on viewport hover</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Well, i mean that the content in the green box should move up without hiding the content in the blue box. Does that make sense?

Comment: Yes, and that's what I built first. Then I re-read "push up" and refactored. Not sure I have time to redo it based on your revisions. Seems like downvotes are inappropriate when folks are trying to help.

Comment: Sorry, my bad for not asking a clear question. Thanks for the help though. Also, i didn't downvote you or anybody else